# Play Protect certification: Device not certified - What does it mean?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-protect

I would like to know what it means when Google Play Protect certifies a device. My Motorola Moto G6 (ali) is not certified in the Play Store.

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| Play Protect certification | About phone |

<sup>(Tap to enlarge)</sup>

Is there any way to certify my device?
Currently, it's running a soak test OTA firmware from Motorola.
Is there a problem if my device isn't certified ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See your Play Protect certification status Google Play Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7165974?visit_id=636805279427759246-2160371819&p=uncertified_device&rd=1) answers you :

> **What it means if your device isn't Play Protect certified**
>
> If your device is not Play Protect certified, Google doesn’t have a record of the Android compatibility test results.
>
> Keep in mind that:
>
> - Devices that aren't Play Protect certified may not be secure.
> - Devices that aren't Play Protect certified may not get Android system updates, or app updates.
> - Google apps on devices that aren't Play Protect certified aren't licensed and may not be real Google apps.
> - Apps and features on devices that aren't Play Protect certified may not work correctly.
> - Data on devices that aren't Play Protect certified may not back up securely.
>
> **What to do if your device isn’t Play Protect certified?**
>
> If your device isn't Play Protect certified, we recommend contacting your device manufacturer. Ask for a fully tested, Play Protect certified device.